# .xltx to .xltm - VSTO project conversion

Tags: vsto

Currently I have an Excel 2007 template project with workbook extension as .xltx. I had a new requirement where my template should run with a Macro (a .xltm template). Since I have a lot of UI changes to the existing template, I do not want to recreate a new template project.

If I change the extension of the workbook file in the template project from .xltx to .xltm, will it work fine without any loss to my design and data? I tried a dummy project and got an error,

Excel cannot open the file 'ExcelTemplate.xltm' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file. Please help.

Regards,

Nanda

Comment: you can't just "change the extension". open your .xltx in Excel and do a "Save As..." to .xltm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your update. Yes, we cannot simply rename. Actually the template I created using VSTO do not support macros. So I need to recreate the template with all the designs using the macro enabled tempalte option selection at the time of template getting created.

If not, while saving, it is showning some errors like template should be macro enabled tempaltes.

Regards,
Nanda